# C# CodeDom Add embedded resource without first dropping file to disk

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, codedom

In CodeDom, it is possible to add an embedded resource to your dynamically created file by using the [CompilerParameters.EmbeddedResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.embeddedresources.aspx) property. In my project, I am adding some bytes of data as an embedded resource to my dynamically created file (as shown below).

```
Byte[] bytes = new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5};

// Write the data to disk (I would like to avoid this step!).
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\EmbeddedResource.exe", bytes); 

CompilerParameters cp;
cp.EmbeddedResources.Add(@"C:\EmbeddedResource.exe");
```

Is there some way I can store the data of 'bytes' in memory, and add it as an embedded resource directly from memory.

Thank you for any advice,

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. Looking into the CSharpCodeGenerator (with Telerik's JustDecompile or Redgate's .NET Reflector), I found the usage of the CompilerParameters class:

```
private string CmdArgsFromParameters(CompilerParameters options)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(128);
    // ...
    StringEnumerator stringEnumerator = options.EmbeddedResources.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (stringEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            string str = stringEnumerator.Current;
            stringBuilder.Append("/res:\"");
            stringBuilder.Append(str);
            stringBuilder.Append("\" ");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable disposable2 = stringEnumerator as IDisposable;
        if (disposable2 != null)
        {
            disposable2.Dispose();
        }
    }
    // ...
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

They use it to create a string with all command-line parameters that are passed to the C# compiler exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). So, at the end, I guess your code is simply compiled with csc.exe.

[]'s